# Unable to focus distance in Camera2 API

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am trying to set focus distance in Android camera2 API but get `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'float java.lang.Float.floatValue()' on a null object reference`. I tried this on Samsung android 10 and it works fine. When I try with redmi photo I get this error, do anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Here is my code:

```
 public void focus(float distance) {
        CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) app.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        CameraCharacteristics characteristics = null;
        try {
            characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraID);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        float minimumLens = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_MINIMUM_FOCUS_DISTANCE);

        float num = (distance * minimumLens / 100);
        captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_OFF);
        captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.LENS_FOCUS_DISTANCE, num);
        refreshCamera();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's Xiaomi... you can't be sure that camera module supports some features like focusing. one and only almost always properly working feature is taking photo/bitmap. all other may be not supported by camera module - even if there is an app on device which can use some feature (e.g. focus) there is no guarantee that manufacturer implemented this feature in Camera2 API (or any other API)

consider using [CameraX](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax) lib, which tries to resolve problems with very different ways for accessing some features/resolutions/params. still it may also fail (but rarely) or return info that camera doesn't support such feature

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is possible to know if that feature exists in some way? It's very important.

Comment: sadly no, thats the problem... Android API delivers possibilities for turning on/off some features, but handling API calls must be implemented by manufacturer of device, and sometimes manufacturer is making own camera app for user, giving some higher permissions and/or access to hidden API for this app and all other camera apps can't use these features... this happens on devices of all manufacturers, more often on "cheaper" models and "essentailly-chinese" manufacturers (e.g. older Xiaomi devices, some Oppo's, realme etc.)

Comment: try to use CameraX lib linked in answer, it can bypass some limitations and have tons of workarounds for such situations. if some feature usage isn't possible with any workaround there is a chance that CameraX would return some error code instead of crash, best it can do in such situation

Comment: consider updating/accepting answer if helpful, good luck!

Comment: ok thanks, this is the only answer i think